# Does Lakhota contrast voicing in stops?

Tags: phonology, consonants, voicing

WALS Online lists Lakhota as only having a voicing contrast in fricatives (referencing a study by Richard Carter in 1974). However, [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakota_language#Consonants) says that it has phonemic voiced bilabial and velar plosives. Which of these is correct? Does anyone here have experience with Lakhota/know anything about it?

Answer (score 4):

In his dissertation, Carter says that Teton Dakota has voiced stops [b, g]. WALS is simply wrong, you would have to ask the author why. There is a [p pʰ b] contrast so we can't even blame misanalysis of [b] as [p].